# Using an Arduino Motor Shield in conjunction a Bluetooth Shield

Tags: c, bluetooth, arduino, microcontroller, robotics

Hopefully this won't be too specific to warrant a question closure.

I'm working with a research group on campus learning about robotics and automation. My current task is learning the insides and outs of the Arduino motor shield and combine it with a bluetooth shield.

We're using [this bluetooth shield](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/bluetooth-shield-p-866.html?cPath=132_134) and [this motor shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoMotorShieldR3). If necessary, we also have access to [this motor shield](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/AdafruitMotorShield).

For the most part, my current code works with each board individually, but when I combine them, suddenly nothing works. The motor portions only work when the bluetooth specific code is commented out. Which leads me to the conclusion that there are pin conflicts. That being said, is there any way that I can get this to work? Any work arounds, etc.

Here's the code I'm using in case it's a problem with my code.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>   // Necessary to use the bluetooth Software Serial Port
#define RxD 7
#define TxD 6

#define DEBUG_ENABLED  1

SoftwareSerial bts(RxD,TxD);

int drive = 12;                    // Pin definitions
int brake = 9;
int power = 3;


const int DRIVE_F = 1;            // Command options returned from parseCommand
const int DRIVE_B = 2;
const int LEFT = 3;
const int RIGHT = 4;
const int STOP = 5;
const int NONE = 0;

void setup() 
{ 
  pinMode(RxD, INPUT);            // Set up pin modes
  pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(drive, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(brake, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(power, 80);

  digitalWrite(drive, LOW);
  digitalWrite(brake, HIGH);
  setupBlueToothConnection();
} 

void loop() 
{ 
    switch(parseCommand())
    {
        case DRIVE_F:                            // Switch through command returns.
              forward();
              bts.println("Driving forward");
              delay(1000);
              fullStop();                        // Go ahead and stop. Don't want
              break;                             // the car to run infinitely yet.

        case DRIVE_B:
              backward();
              bts.println("Driving backward");
              delay(1000);
              fullStop();
              break;


         case LEFT:
              turnLeft();                        // These do nothing for now. Just here for later.
              break;

         case RIGHT:
              turnRight();
              break;


         case STOP:
             fullStop();
             bts.println("Stopping");            // Stop the car. Will be needed later.
             break;

         default:
             turnLeft();                        // If invalid command returned,
             delay(250);                        // wiggle wheels for an error message.
             turnRight();
             delay(250);
             turnStraight();
             break;
    }
} 

void setupBlueToothConnection()                // Not exactly sure why all this is needed. It was in the sample code, so I kept it all
{
  bts.begin(38400); //Set BluetoothBee BaudRate to default baud rate 38400
  bts.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n"); //set the bluetooth work in slave mode
  bts.print("\r\n+STNA=SeeedBTSlave\r\n"); //set the bluetooth name as "SeeedBTSlave"
  bts.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n"); // Permit Paired device to connect me
  bts.print("\r\n+STAUTO=0\r\n"); // Auto-connection should be forbidden here
  delay(2000); // This delay is required.
  bts.print("\r\n+INQ=1\r\n"); //make the slave bluetooth inquirable 
  Serial.println("The slave bluetooth is inquirable!");
  delay(2000); // This delay is required.
  bts.flush();
}

void forward()
{
    digitalWrite(drive, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(brake, LOW);
}

void backward()
{
    digitalWrite(drive, LOW);
    digitalWrite(brake, LOW);
}

void fullStop()
{
    digitalWrite(brake, HIGH);
}

void turnRight()
{

}

void turnLeft()
{

}

void turnStraight()
{

}

int parseCommand()
{
    String command = "";                        // String to hold the command
    char recvChar;                              // Char to hold each character.
    while(true)
    {
        if(bts.available())
        {
            recvChar = bts.read();
            if(recvChar == 13)
                bts.println();                // If char received is an ASCII 13, carriage-return/enter key
            else                              // print new line.
                bts.print(recvChar);          // Else, print received char to serial so user can see his/her input.


            if(recvChar != -1 && recvChar != 13)
                command += recvChar;        // If not -1 (no input received from read()) or 13, concat it with command

            if(recvChar == 13)
            {                               // If enter pressed, check the command variable.
                if( command == "forward" )
                    return DRIVE_F;
                else if( command == "back" || command == "backward")
                    return DRIVE_B;
                else if( command == "stop" )
                    return STOP;
                else
                {
                    bts.println("'" + command + "' is an invalid command.");
                    return NONE;           // If invalid, return NONE and print error.
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the two shields, I suspect a pin conflict over pin 6.  The Arduino Motor Shield exposes "2 TinkerKit connectors for two Aanlog Outputs (in orange in the middle), connected to PWM outputs on pins D5 and D6."  They may have a pull down or pull up resistor on D6 which would interfere with your Bluetooth UART communications.

Is there a way to route your bluetooth communications over pins 0 & 1 instead?  You'd have to use Bluetooth instead of USB if you did this.

Perhaps a simpler approach would be to switch to a motor shield that's *just* a motor shield and takes fewer pins.  Something like the [Ardumotor from Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9815) that only uses pins [3, 11, 12, and 13](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/DevTools/Arduino/Ardumoto_v13.pdf).

And now there's a [dedicated group for robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't have my board in front of me at the moment. Aren't 0 and 1 used for system TX/RX? Even still, we've never gotten the shield to work on any other pins than 6 and 7 (yes, we remembered to move the jumpers). I'm in a class right now, but I'll be working on it later today.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?